# setOnFocusChangeListener not being called in Fragment Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my fragment setOnFocusChangeListener() is no being called. What could be the reason? onToch and onClick are working fine.
Here's my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_barcode_detail,
            container, false);
editText_barcode = (EditText) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.editText_barcode);

editText_barcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                            editos = (EditText) v;
                            System.out.println("====onf== "+editos);
                            key.showCustomNumKeyboard(v);
                        } else {
                            key.hideCustomNumKeyboard();
                        }
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: **Suggestion:** I see you are using `setOnFocusChangeListener` for `editText_barcode` "explicitly", so you can remove the *switch-case* construct from `onFocusChange` and just keep the code you want to execute.

Comment: I removed switch case and keep my code that I want to execute. It didn't solve my problem. :(

Comment: Have you checked logging without making if else condition in callback method of **onFocusChange**

Comment: And can you show the xml code where you have defined edittext

Comment: Yes I did. onFocusChange() is skipped always.

Comment: Here's my XML code:


    <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_barcode"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
  
                    android:hint="Barcode" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

Comment: I am guessing you want to show/hide keypad as your code says. So is it not  working for one time also??? but as far as the way you code, It should work for one time but not for second time until unless the focused wouldn't change from edittext.

Comment: No its not even working one time also. The onFocusChange() is skipped while execution and onClick, onTouch listeners are working perfectly. :(

Comment: remove <requestFocus> fro  your xml

Comment: I did but it didn't work either. So frustrated of this issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Focus is generally requested whenever that view is loaded on screen and you need to grab attention of user.For a view to get focus need to add two attribute `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` with that View and then requestFocus

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/editText_barcode" 
  ...required attributes
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"> 
<requestFocus /> 
</EditText>
```

Also your are setting `onFocusChangeListener()` as below make sure it is `View.onFocusChangeListener()` So suggest you to change below code

```
editText_barcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
```

to

```
editText_barcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
```

Also after checking whether `hasFocus` I would request you to change it to

```
        Log.d(TAG,"EditTextBarcode has Focus value " + hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) {
                   Log.d(TAG,"EditTextBarcode has Focus")
                   key.showCustomNumKeyboard(v);
                } else {
                   Log.d(TAG,"EditTextBarcode does not have Focus")
                   key.hideCustomNumKeyboard();
                }
```

Comment: I tried this way and all other ways hell lot time but it didn't help. onFocusChange() is skipped while executing. I can't figure out why

Comment: Please try this one more time with the log in either cases and make sure it View.OnFocusChangeListener along with two attribute in the xml file.

Comment: Are you sure that your view is Visible on screen....It is not hidden or partial visible on screen...because in that case it won't work.... Also make sure some other view  is not requesting Focus in the hierarchy

Comment: yes its visible and not other view is requesting focus.

Comment: Are you sure not even single log statement where logged out of 3 stmts  even when you type something in edittext ?forget the showing/hiding of keyboard for now comment them...If yes then In that case add the complete Fragment and Activity code along with respective layout file

Comment: yes no even single log statement logged out. Please see my Fragment and XML [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098130/custom-keyboard-not-working-in-fragment)

Comment: @SheenaTyagi Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92229/discussion-between-shadow-droid-and-sheena-tyagi).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is the switch case. Remove the switch case and it will work.
  View's id returned in your FocusChange listener will be of 
  `editText_barcode` always.So your `switchcase` is failing since you are trying       to match with another id.

Comment: I've removed Switch case and it isn't working either. Please have a look at my edited code.

Comment: try   'editText_barcode.clearfocus() in your 'onCreate'

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 your activity implement OnFocusChangeListener

 In onCreateView()
 editText_barcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

 @Override
 public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
 switch(v.getId()){
 case r.id.editText_barcode:

      //code here

 break;

...etc
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using Fragment and initialization is in onCreateView()

Comment: Earlier I was doing execution by this way only. I didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

`setOnFocusChangeListener` is buggy sometimes. Try `setOnTouchListener`.

```
editText_barcode = (EditText) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.editText_barcode);
editText_barcode.clearFocus()
editText_barcode.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // Your code here
            return false;
        }


});
```